# Font face not showing in IE https

Tags: internet-explorer, http, https, font-face

I have the following codes (see below). The font is displaying correctly in Chrome and Firefox in case of https and http. But in IE the font is not displaying when the url is https, but it is displaying just fine in http. What am I doing wrong. Have been searching all over the internet and tried many ways, but no success.

Has someone any ideas on this?

```
@font-face {

  font-family: 'NotoSans';

  src: url('../NotoSans-webfont.eot');

  src: url('../NotoSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),

        url('../NotoSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 

        url('../NotoSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),

        url('../NotoSans-webfont.svg') format('svg');

  font-weight: '400';

  font-style: 'normal'; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using HTML5. You can try including minified shiv in your  section. This should enable the HTML5 elements for your IE.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Don't forget to download the script before including. You can get it directly from here: https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv